# Converting the caps in an NSString into lowercase

Tags: iphone

I have a issue while doing some encoding with the string. It returns all the values in CAPS.
I want it to be small. Is there any api available in objective C to convert the caps in the NSString into small alphabet?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

If you want it all lower case you can do `[myString lowercaseString];`

If you want it capitalized use `[myString capitalizedString];`

See [Apple's Docs on NSString](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/lowercaseString)

Comment: This comes in handy as well [myString uppercaseString]

Answer (score 18):

```
 NSString *original = @"blah"
 NSString *lowercase = [original lowercaseString];
```

This code will make the NSString `lowercase` be `original` in all lower case.

Answer (score 9):

[lowercaseString](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-lowercaseString)

(is there a badge for the fourth answer providing the same solution as the three before?)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use a specific locale (the NSString docs don't seem to indicate what locale the upper/lowercase/capitalise methods use) then you need to use a CFString function:

```
NSString* inputString = @"input";
NSString* outputString;
NSLocale* locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"tr_TR"];

CFMutableStringRef tempCFMString = CFStringCreateMutableCopy(NULL, 0, (CFStringRef)inputString);
CFStringCapitalize(tempCFMString, (CFLocaleRef)locale);
outputString = [[(NSString*)tempCFMString copy] autorelease];
CFRelease(tempCFMString);

//remember to release stuff
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[NSString lowercaseString]
```

Returns a lowercase version of your NSString.

Answer (score 1):

*When you want to directly convert the string then*,

```
NSString *str = @"HELLO";
[str lowercaseString];
```

*while you are entering text from textfield then,*

```
[textField.text lowercaseString];
```

**textField** is an outlet of UITextField